# Sticky element not scrolling up with sibling element?

Tags: html, css

This is an extension to my previous question

[How to make an element sticky but scrollable to its full (variable) height with sibling element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75469958/how-to-make-an-element-sticky-but-scrollable-to-its-full-variable-height-with)

Issue here is the right sidebar does scroll to its full available content and then becomes sticky and user can scroll the main section whatever available content, similar to what's happening in twitter. But the problem is when user scrolls up, right sidebar doesn't scrolls up until the user reaches to the very top of the page? (you can increase columns heights to get more insights)

How can I solve this?

**Working Solution**

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;

document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  document.querySelector('.right-sidebar').classList.toggle('scroll_down', st > lastScrollTop);
  lastScrollTop = st <= 0 ? 0 : st;
}, false);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.inner-grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.left-sidebar,
.right-sidebar,
.main {
  margin: 0 1rem;
}

.left-sidebar,
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.content {
  height: 95%;
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
}

.left-sidebar {
  background-color: burlywood;
  height: 100vh;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.main {
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 3000px;
}

.right-sidebar {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  position: sticky;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 1000px;
  top: 0;
}

.scroll_down {
  top: unset;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.fixed-header {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  width: auto;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-sidebar">
    <div>
      <div>left sidebar</div>
      <div>top</div>
    </div>
    <div>bottom</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-grid-container">
    <div class="main">
      <div class="fixed-header">fixed header</div>
      <div class="content">
        <div>
          <div>main</div>
          <div>top</div>
        </div>
        <div>bottom</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-sidebar">
      <div class="fixed-header">fixed header</div>
      <div class="" style="margin-top: 2.5rem;">
        <div>
          <div>right sidebar</div>
          <div>top</div>
        </div>
        <p style="font-size: 1rem;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde iste, repudiandae quasi, cumque mollitia animi, libero dolores aliquam ipsam optio veritatis tempore eius. Nemo magni molestiae quis similique itaque dolorem quisquam, neque odit debitis
          earum deleniti ut natus distinctio ipsa repellendus tempore voluptatem cupiditate sunt delectus quo? Pariatur, quis modi natus molestiae quibusdam quod, dolore perferendis deserunt deleniti fugit, fuga voluptas a numquam accusamus quam aliquam?
          Ipsa necessitatibus perspiciatis sunt eaque, incidunt vitae, labore autem, quos voluptatibus numquam commodi earum non iusto. Sapiente quis, praesentium maxime odit, eligendi libero illo necessitatibus deserunt nisi, assumenda culpa ducimus
          cum debitis dolores sequi?</p>
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/674010/pexels-photo-674010.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" width="150" height="300" alt="">
        <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0;">bottom</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a twitter page with that right sidebar functionality

#### Check this might work for you

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;

document.addEventListener("scroll", function(){ 
   var st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop; 
      document.querySelector('.right_parent').classList.toggle('scroll_down',st > lastScrollTop);
   lastScrollTop = st <= 0 ? 0 : st; // For Mobile or negative scrolling
}, false);
```

```css
    .left
    {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .head
    {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: white;
    }

    .right_parent
    {
        position: sticky;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0 !important;
        margin-top: 0;
    }


    .scroll_down
    {
        position: sticky;
        top: -50% !important;
        margin-top: inherit;
    }



    .left a
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: black;
    }
    .left button
    {
        padding: 12px;
        color: white;
        border:none;
        background: #1D9BF0;
        border-radius: 30px;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .section_pane
    {
        border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }

    .section
    {
        border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }

    .head button
    {
        background: white;
        border:none;
        
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .active
    {
        font-weight: bold;
        border-bottom: 5px solid #1D9BF0 !important;
    }

    .search
    {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
        border-radius: 20px;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 80%;
    }

    .mid
    {
        min-height: 100vh;
    }

    .right > div
    {
    border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    border-radius: 15px;
    }

    .right h3
    {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .right h5
    {
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    .right h6
    {
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .right p
    {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .fill
    {
        border:none !important;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.02);
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<div class="container"> 
<div class="row align-items-stretch">   
<div class="col-3 left d-flex flex-column px-5">
    <h3 class="mb-4"><i class="bi bi-twitter"></i></h3>
    <a href="#/" class="mb-3"><i class="bi bi-house me-2"></i> Home</a>
    <a href="#/" class="mb-3"><i class="bi bi-search me-2"></i> Explore</a>
    <a href="#/" class="mb-3"><i class="bi bi-bell me-2"></i> Notification</a>
    <a href="#/" class="mb-3"><i class="bi bi-envelope me-2"></i> Messages</a>
    <a href="#/" class="mb-5"><i class="bi bi-card-list me-2"></i> List</a>
    <button>Post</button>
</div>
<div class="col-6 mid d-flex flex-column flex-grow-1 section_pane px-0">
    <div class="head pt-2 section px-3">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-3">
        <button><i class="bi bi-arrow-left"></i></button>
        <div class="search px-4"><i class="bi bi-search"></i></div>
        <button><i class="bi bi-three-dots"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex">
            <button class="w-100 active">Top</button>
            <button class="w-100">Latest</button>
            <button class="w-100">People</button>
            <button class="w-100">Media</button>
            <button class="w-100">Lists</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content section py-3 px-3">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content section py-3 px-3">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content section py-3 px-3">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content section py-3 px-3">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content section py-3 px-3">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content section py-3 px-3">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content section py-3 px-3">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content section py-3 px-3">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content section py-3 px-3">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content section py-3 px-3">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content section py-3 px-3">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content section py-3 px-3">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content section py-3 px-3">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content section py-3 px-3">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content section py-3 px-3">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content section py-3 px-3">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.
        </p>
    </div>


    <div class="content section py-3 px-3">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content section py-3 px-3">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content section py-3 px-3">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content section py-3 px-3">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content section py-3 px-3">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content section py-3 px-3">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="content section py-3 px-3">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat.
        </p>
    </div>


</div>
<div class="col-3 right_parent pt-3">
    <div class="right">

    <div class="px-3 py-2 mb-3">
        <h3>Search Filter</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="fill px-3 py-2 mb-3">
        <h5>Whats Happening 1</h5>
        <div class="mb-2">
            <p class="mb-0">US Open</p>
            <h6>US Open Tennis 2023</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-2">
            <p class="mb-0">Abcdef</p>
            <h6>Abcdef 2024</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-2">
            <p class="mb-0">Abcdef</p>
            <h6>Abcdef 2024</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-2">
            <p class="mb-0">Abcdef</p>
            <h6>Abcdef 2024</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-2">
            <p class="mb-0">Abcdef</p>
            <h6>Abcdef 2024</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-2">
            <p class="mb-0">Abcdef</p>
            <h6>Abcdef 2024</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-2">
            <p class="mb-0">Abcdef</p>
            <h6>Abcdef 2024</h6>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fill px-3 py-2 mb-3">
        <h5>Whats Happening 2</h5>
        <div class="mb-2">
            <p class="mb-0">France Open</p>
            <h6>France Open Tennis 2023</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-2">
            <p class="mb-0">Abcdef</p>
            <h6>Abcdef 2024</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-2">
            <p class="mb-0">France Open</p>
            <h6>France Open Tennis 2023</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-2">
            <p class="mb-0">France Open</p>
            <h6>France Open Tennis 2023</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-2">
            <p class="mb-0">France Open</p>
            <h6>France Open Tennis 2023</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-2">
            <p class="mb-0">France Open</p>
            <h6>France Open Tennis 2023</h6>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="fill px-3 py-2 mb-3">
        <h5>Whats Happening 3</h5>
        <div class="mb-2">
            <p class="mb-0">France Open</p>
            <h6>France Open Tennis 2023</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-2">
            <p class="mb-0">Abcdef</p>
            <h6>Abcdef 2024</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-2">
            <p class="mb-0">France Open</p>
            <h6>France Open Tennis 2023</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-2">
            <p class="mb-0">France Open</p>
            <h6>France Open Tennis 2023</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-2">
            <p class="mb-0">France Open</p>
            <h6>France Open Tennis 2023</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-2">
            <p class="mb-0">France Open</p>
            <h6>France Open Tennis 2023</h6>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="fill px-3 py-2 mb-3 bottom">
        <h5>Whats Happening 4</h5>
        <div class="mb-2">
            <p class="mb-0">StackOverflow</p>
            <h6>AI Conference</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-2">
            <p class="mb-0">StackOverflow</p>
            <h6>AI Conference</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-2">
            <p class="mb-0">StackOverflow</p>
            <h6>AI Conference</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-2">
            <p class="mb-0">StackOverflow</p>
            <h6>AI Conference</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-2">
            <p class="mb-0">StackOverflow</p>
            <h6>AI Conference</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-2">
            <p class="mb-0">StackOverflow</p>
            <h6>AI Conference</h6>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>

</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: your solution didn't quite work for me but it did provide hints and I was able to find a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> While playing with it, I quickly noticed that when an element with a `position: sticky` style is wrapped, and it is the only element inside the wrapper element, this element, which was defined `position: sticky` will not stick.

So try to make the right sidebar completely apart from any other html divs as quote:

> The reason for that is that when an element is given the position: sticky style, the sticky item’s container is the only area in which the sticky item can stick. The item doesn’t have any elements to float over since it can only float over sibling elements, which, being an only child, it doesn’t have.

https://elad.medium.com/css-position-sticky-how-it-really-works-54cd01dc2d46

Comment: So, could you create a code snippet that represents the working solution?

Comment: please provide a working snippet,

there is still the same issue even with a 3 column grid layout, right sidebar doesn't scroll up until the user scrolls to the top of the page

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).